How to make anchor text in HTML
I am new to HTML and I'm trying to create an anchor link to a website, but I'm having trouble getting it to work correctly. Specifically, I want to create a clickable link to this website: https://popitopi.com.
Here is the code I am using:
<a hrefs="https://popitopi.com">PDF</a>
When I test this code, the link does not work as expected. I suspect there might be a mistake in my HTML syntax, but I can't figure out what it is. Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong and explain the correct way to create an anchor link?
I believe the issue might be with the attribute I'm using in the <a> tag. Is there a specific attribute required to make a hyperlink function properly in HTML? Additionally, if there are any best practices for creating anchor links, such as using specific attributes or tags, I would love to learn about those as well.
Any guidance or resources on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

The issue with your HTML code is a small typo in the attribute name. In your  tag, you used hrefs instead of href. The correct attribute to create a hyperlink is href not hrefs.
